# program.cs file is missing in windows and console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Have recently installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 express. 
The problem is that if i open windows application or console application, it is not showing program.cs (default) file. Please can some body help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: what does your screen look like after you've created your application?

Comment: Do you mean you're opening an existing solution or project file? There's nothing to say there *has* to be a `Program.cs` file...

Comment: New project or existing project?

Comment: Try to repair or reinstal visual studio. It can be corrupted template...

Comment: if i open new project or open existing project it should me program.cs file. but it is not showing.

Comment: For New Project yes, but for existing project, it depends. I think reinstalling is the best choice for this case.

Comment: You're not giving us enough information here. Could you provide a step by step instruction of exactly what you do and what you expect (in the form of *step1: I open VS...*)?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio (2005/ 2008/ 2010/ 2012), when you create a new winforms application or console application, Visual Studio adds automatically a class called `Program` (`Program.cs)`. But if you open an existing project in Visual Studio, it is not **has to be** a `Program.cs`. Existing project doesn't has to be a class called `Program`.

I think some operations corrupt your `Winforms` and `Console` templates in Visual Studio. For this case, reinstalling and installing looks best solution for you.