# How do you set the startup page for debugging in an WinAPP Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I set the main form for the debugging when i hit start it goes to the form that i don't want to set at the first page.

Answer (score 1):

Well as it's Winform application you can't do it likewise ASP.NET application. In your `Program.cs` under `Main()` method you have something called `Application.Run()` and you need to set the form there by giving an instance of the said Form.

Comment: I can't find *Program.cs* in the solution explorer

Comment: Check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219899/program-cs-file-is-missing-in-windows-and-console-application]